# Node static js file isn't refreshing

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express

I'm trying to build my first node app and am having problems with the javascript file, but not my css so I'm very confused. Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I couldn't load my js file until I added line 4, where I saw in the chrome console "connected", which was from my js file. The problem that I am having is that since I added line 4, express.static my js file hasn't changed and everything that I have added in the file is not showing in the chrome resources tab. Strangely though, my css file is working correctly, so I'm a little bit stumped.

I am trying linking to the js file like:

```
<script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

I'm not really sure why its not working properly, I tried restarting the server and have since installed nodemon which hasn't worked either. my folder structure is

```
app.js
public
    stylesheets
        main.css
    javascripts
        main.js
```

I have looked up the problem and have only found people not connecting to static files, not once connected they aren't showing any saved changes

Comment: Can you try with

    <script src="./javascripts/main.js"></script>

 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you must disable cache in your browser. Because browser think that file is not to old to be refresh from server and use cached file.
For Chrome - open console by `F12` (also in other browser works) and check it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Aikon, I checked the network tab and it was already unchecked

Comment: You must check it. It's denied use local-cache to browser.

Comment: Try clear cache manual by browser setting and try again. I sure that it's a cache problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an absolute path to ensure static assets get loaded properly. Using relative paths (e.g. `javascripts/main.js`) can be problematic because of the way the browser converts them to absolute paths (it takes into account the full url, including any nested routes).

So for example if you have a route `/foo/bar` set up and you are using relative paths, when you visit `/foo/bar` in your browser, the browser will try to access `/foo/bar/javascripts/main.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried `src="./javascripts/main.js"` and also `src="/javascripts/main.js"` but I'm still only seeing "connected" and not the rest of the js file

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is already answered by the library like webpack. It does hot reloading. Whatever the changes you make to your web app, will be loaded into client and the files will be patched to update the changes without having to restart the server. You will have updated scripts running in the browser.

Comment: Hi Nishanth, I have installed nodemon that is now autoupdating the server but the res of my main.js file isn't loading properly

Comment: you need to update the client files. Look at hot reloading library's like webpack or hr4R. When these library make changes you will see the change logs on your browser console.

Comment: I'm using nodemon to do that and it does refresh my html and css, just not my js file